# extract specific records with dos

Tags: dos

I have a very large text file from which I want to extract only records which contain a specific zip code and do so with DOS.

I see many examples but none that do specifically what I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean actual DOS (i.e., from the early 1990s) or do you mean the Windows command line?

Comment: Thanks for posting a question here on SO. At first glance it looks like you do have an on-topic question, but you're going to need to add a little more detail before anyone can give you a helpful answer. Firstly resolve the confusion regarding the term DOS, secondly can you provide an example of the file format you are trying to parse (just a few lines), thirdly show what format your results need to be in.

Comment: "I see many examples but none that do specifically what I need." You won't get any examples that do specifically what you need if you don't come back and explain what you specifically need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FINDSTR.

You can type:

```
FINDSTR /?
```

to get help on the command if you aren't going to show us your data.

Here are some examples that should help:

First, I show you my file, called "file.txt"

```
E:\>TYPE file.txt 
Line 1,MA01824
Line 2,NY10017
Tricky line,SomethingNY10017Something
```

Now I search for a simple ZIP like "MA01824" and it works

```
E:\>FINDSTR "MA01824" file.txt 
Line 1,MA01824
```

Now I search for a ZIP that occurs twice, once correctly and once embedded within another string

```
E:\>FINDSTR "NY10017" file.txt 
Line 2,NY10017
Tricky line,SomethingNY10017Something
```

Ooops, that failed. Add a regular expression meaning "only find at start of word"

```
E:\>FINDSTR /r "\<NY10017" file.txt 
Line 2,NY10017
```

How about if user looks for a lower case ZIP when they are upper case in the file - no problem, just make the search case-insensitive with "/i"

```
E:\>FINDSTR /i "ma01824" file.txt 
Line 1,MA01824
```

If you want to save the output of any command above into a new file, rather than see it on the screen, just add a greater than (>) and filename at the end of the command like this:

```
FINDSTR "MA01824" > MassZIPcode.txt
```

**Be careful not to overwrite your input file by specifying the same name for the output file!!!**

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\>FIND /?

Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.
```

so it will be something like `FIND "010010" mydata.txt`